# Classes and Objects on charm are returning extra parentheses, quotations and comma. Need help to get rid of them

Tags: python, class, object, pycharm

I'm relatively new to python and coding. Here's what I did for classes and objects using pycharm:

```
class Student:
def __init__(self, name, major, gpa, probation):
    self.name = name,
    self.major = major,
    self.gpa = gpa,
    self.probation = probation,

Jim = Student('Jim', 'cs', 2.5, False)

print(Jim.name)
```

And here's what it returns:

```
('Jim',)
```

I don't think I'm supposed to get those extra parentheses, quotations and comma.
Need help on how to get rid of them

Comment: The trailing commas make all the attributes *tuples*.

Comment: Yep, `name,` in `self.name = name,` is a tuple of one element, the same as `(name,)`. Same for all other attributes.

Comment: sweet!!!! it worked out. tyty :D

Comment: u know what....i honestly dont know...its like i saw some wisps xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the commas:

```
class Student:
 def __init__(self, name, major, gpa, probation):
   self.name = name
   self.major = major
   self.gpa = gpa
   self.probation = probation

Jim = Student('Jim', 'cs', 2.5,  False)

print(Jim.name)
```

Comment: You could add the information from the comments above to your answer, these would add very important details to future readers